# Doesn't access xls files in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, permissions, netoffice

i am trying open xls file and convert to pdf using web api 2 service.
When i start service project in vs 2013 everyting works fine, but when i publish the service to iis 8.0 and try to open excel file i got error:

**Error:**

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers,
>   Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
>       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)
>       at NetOffice.Invoker.MethodReturn(COMObject comObject, String name, Object[] paramsArray)

---

**Error on this line:**

```
var workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelLocalOutput, 0, false, 5, 123, 123, true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

---

**What i tryied to solve this:**

> i gave "Network Service" and "IUSRS" permission to Microsoft Excel
>   Application
>
> i gave "Network Service" to application pool
>
> i gave "Network Service" to published folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR; NetOffice is the wrong library to do what you want. It is not meant to be used on a server, and **you should not have Excel installed on the server**.

---

NetOffice is a COM Interop library that allows you to interact with the Excel installed on a user's machine running a Windows Client.

**Microsoft does not support Excel on Windows Server** as described its famous [KB257757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) - [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

To read Excel files on a server you should use tools that can read/write Excel files directly, **without** requiring Excel installed on the server.

If you are reading Excel 2017+ files (i.e. `.xlsx`), you could use the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), or any other `OpenXml`-compatible library such as [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML).

If you need to read older Excel files (i.e. `.xls`), you could use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) or similar library that can read the old Excel binary file format.

Comment: i need to export xls,xlsm files to pdf, which library do u prefer ?